# Sending an SMS using an api in php

Tags: php

I am trying to send out an sms using a BulkSMS api from which I have an acccount. Now every time I pass in a text along with with the number I'm trying to send to, I'm getting a 400 status = Bad Request.

***Here in my code:***

```
$sms_to;
$sms_from;
$message_body;

$base_url;
$cUrl;
$http_status;
```

Avoid sending duplicated sms(s) to the server

```
function cut_id_duplication() {
   return 0;
}
```

Getting the fields sent out in an array

```
function post_body( $post_fields )
{
    $id = cut_id_duplication();

    if ( $id > 0 )
    {
        $post_fields['id'] = cut_id_duplication();
    }

    $post_fields = '';

    foreach ( $post_fields as $key => $value )
    {
        $post_fields .= urlencode( $key ). '=' . urlencode( $value ) . '&';
    }

    $post_fields = rtrim( $post_fields, '&' );

    return $post_fields;
}
```

Function used to send out an sms along with a status: e.g 'https://api.bulksms.com/v1/messages'

```
function send_messages( $msg, $status )
{
   return curl_function( $msg, $status );
}
```

Curl Script code and it's settings

```
private function curl_function( $post_values, $function = '')
{
    $base_url = 'https://api.bulksms.com/v1/'.$function;

    $cUrl = curl_init();

    $method = '';

    if ( $method == null )
    {
        $method == "GET";
    }
    else
    {
        $method == "POST";
    }

    $post_fields = post_body( $post_values );

    curl_setopt( $cUrl, CURLOPT_URL, $base_url  ); 
    curl_setopt( $cUrl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method );
    curl_setopt( $cUrl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $cUrl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields );
    curl_setopt( $cUrl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

     $output = curl_exec( $cUrl );

     $http_status = curl_getinfo( $cUrl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );

     if ( $http_status == 400 ) 
     {
         echo ("Return code is {$http_status}: Bad Request");
         return false;
     }

     if(curl_errno( $cUrl ))
         echo curl_errno( $cUrl );

     if(curl_error($cUrl))
         echo curl_error( $cUrl );

     curl_close( $cUrl );

     return $output;
}
```

Array var to store sending-out-msg

```
   $send_out_message = array(
   'from'  => $sms_from,
   'to'    => $sms_to,
   'body'  => $message_body
  );
```

call out send_messages() function

```
  $send_collective = send_messages( json_encode( $send_out_message ), 'messages' );

        if ( !$send_collective )
        {
            echo( 'ERROR SENDING OUT SMS.' );
            exit();
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried asking the service provider? It's their service after all so they should be able to see what's going on and how their service should be used. SO is not a general "every-service-on-internet"-helpdesk.

Comment: Yes, I have but i was given a link http://developer.bulksms.com/json/v1/errors/ to look out __server errors__

Comment: _"bad-request - Indicates that there is a problem with the request; usually a validation error on a property or parameter. The error code is 400 Bad Request."_. So you might be passing the wrong parameters or in an invalid format?

Comment: This is not a good question here on SO since it's basically about "How do I use this service?". If you can't figure out what's wrong, then contact them again and explain your issue again.